# How many apps are allowed on a 'Hobby' Heroku plan?

Tags: heroku

A 'Free' tier Heroku account allows up to 5 apps. How many apps does a 'Hobby' plan allow for?

I have looked on the Heroku [general pricing page](https://www.heroku.com/pricing), [detailed pricing page](https://www.heroku.com/pricing#dyno-comparison), and on a few related pages [e.g. 'Choosing the Right Heroku Postgres Plan'](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans), but I can't see any explicit mention of how many apps I can deploy

Could it be that a "Dyno" is in fact another word for an app? And therefore there is no limit on the 'Hobby' tier, but I must pay $7/app/month?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In case it's useful to someone else the answer is:

"there is a soft limit of 100 apps per (Hobby tier) account".

The quote comes from my email to Heroku support

Comment: Do you mean from standard plan will not limit number of apps?

Comment: 100 apps means 100 * $7 = $700 bill per month or 100 apps still will be charged maximum $7/month?

Answer (score 9):

Although the question was on the Hobby plan, there is an update now that lets you have more than 5 apps for the Free plan (which is one reason one might have asked this question).

If you verify the account by adding a credit card on file, you can have up to 100 apps on the (verified) free plan, and still the 5 app limit for unverified.

[Source (Heroku link)](https://www.heroku.com/free)

Answer (score 1):

According to the new rules, one can at most 5 apps if the account is not verified (no credit card details). If you add your credit card, you can have as many as 100 free apps as your account is now verified.

If we talk about free dynos, it's 550 for un-verified accounts and an additional 450 for verified accounts.

Reference: https://www.heroku.com/free